# Check if canvas child exists

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

So I'm adding rectangles from a list to my canvas and if I add the same one again I get this error: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

this is my code to add:

```
_canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

Is there anyway I could check if child: rect already exists?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not do `_canvas.Children.Contains(rect)` ??